# Expected frequency of replacements

Tags: probability

How exactly do you answer the following question?:

"Any given day there is a malfunction on a plane with probability 1/10 which then requires a replacement. Additionally, each plane that has been around for 100 days must be replaced. What is the long-term frequency of replacements?"

If $X$=number of days until replacement then does $X$ follow a geometric distribution up to $99$ ($F_X(x)=1-(9/10)^{-x}$) and $F_X(100)=1$ ? Are we then asked to find $EX$? That's pretty easy, but I am not sure if I am understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Have you understood my answer? Any reply is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exactly: "long-term frequency of replacements" means exactly the average time of replacement you will have in a long term of activity.

As you noted, the pmf is truncated in $t=100$. Obviously this truncation does not significantly affect the result, thus in this situation the requested frequency is $10$ without any calculations.

***You can try to solve your problem with a different truncation***, i.e. $t=20$ in order to appreciate the different results with or without truncation

So I would first calculate the truncated pmf

$$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{1-0.9^{20}}\cdot 0.1\cdot 0.9^{x-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{1;2;3;\dots;20\}}(x)$$

Comment: @nameless: an update: I would not calulate the average as you proposed but I would  first calculate the truncated pmf and then the average...the result is not the same

Answer (score 0):

I would regard the interval $t\in\{1,2,\cdots, 100\}$ only. Then you have the same situation vor the following intervals. The random variable $X$ denotes the number of replacements in the interval.

- You have one replacement in 100 days, if you have no replacement in
  the first 99 days. Thus, for $x=1$, the probability is $0.9^{99}$.
- You have two replacements in 100 days, if you have one replacement in
  the first 99 days. Thus, for $x=2$, the probability is $\binom{99}{1}\cdot 0.9^{98}\cdot 0.1$.

$$\vdots$$

- You have 100 replacements in 100 days, if you have 99 replacements in
  the first 99 days. Thus, for $x=100$, the probability is $\binom{99}{99}\cdot 0.9^{0}\cdot 0.1^{99}$.

From these cases we can deduce a probability function:

$$P(X=x)=\binom{99}{x-1}\cdot 0.9^{100-x}\cdot 0.1^{x-1}, \quad x\in \{1,2,\ldots , 100\}$$

From here you can deduce the expected value.

**Remark:**

The long-term period of replacement is $p=\frac{100}{\mathbb E(X)}$